# Attach a div to Dojo DataGrid horizontal scroll

Tags: datagrid, dojo, scroll

I have a fixed width datagrid being built programatically, and am trying to put a header over top of it that will scroll with it.  I can't do it as part of the grid as that destroys the fixed width of the cells.

I would like to be able to scroll the top div as the scrollbar for the DataGrid scrolls.  This seems how the header works already, so it should be possible.  I just can't figure out how to link/attach it.

Comment: Didn't you post this to the dojo mailing list too?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out... if anyone is interested.  You need to extend _View to include what you want to update.  The hardest part about this is getting the div structure laid out so it works in IE and FF, just really duplicated what was there for the datagrid header that was already being scrolled.  Here is the declare:

```
dojo.declare("custom.View", dojox.grid._View, {
    doscroll: function(inEvent) {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        var customHeader = dojo.byId('customGridHeader');
        if (customHeader) {
            customHeader.scrollLeft = this.scrollboxNode.scrollLeft;
        }
    },

    update: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        var customHeader = dojo.byId('customGridHeader');
        if (customHeader) {
            customHeader.scrollLeft = this.scrollboxNode.scrollLeft;
        }
    }
});
```